# how could i respawn an item box after it was turned "inactive?" Also I'm using the 2019 version of C# script

Tags: c#

I have this down, but every time i played and collided with the box, it has the error message: Coroutine couldn't be started because the game object 'itemBox(Clone)' is inactive.

```
private void itemBoxRespawn()
{
    gameObject.SetActive(true);
}

private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision other)
{
    if (other.gameObject.tag == "Player")
    {
        gameObject.SetActive(false);
    }

    if (other.gameObject.tag == "Player")
    {
        StartCoroutine(RespawnItemBox());
    }
}

IEnumerator RespawnItemBox()
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(respawnTime);
    Instantiate(itemBoxPrefab, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
}
```

I have tried putting gameObject.SetActive(false); and StartCoroutine(RespawnItemBox()); in the same code line but it didnt work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

So first in this function both the if statement conditions are the same so both lines of code will run, hence this gameObject will be not active and not able to start the Coroutine

```
if (other.gameObject.tag == "Player")
{
    gameObject.SetActive(false);
}

if (other.gameObject.tag == "Player")
{
    StartCoroutine(RespawnItemBox());
}
```

To fix this you can ensure it's active before calling StartCoroutine and set it inactive after the Coroutine is completed, like so:

```
private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision other)
{
    if (other.gameObject.tag == "Player")
    {
        gameObject.SetActive(true);
        StartCoroutine(RespawnItemBox());
    }
}

IEnumerator RespawnItemBox()
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(respawnTime);
    Instantiate(itemBoxPrefab, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
    gameObject.SetActive(false);
}
```

Good luck with your project :)

Comment: no problem!!! :D